# How can I reduce the size of an html file that I created with ggplotly/plotly?

Tags: r, plotly, filesize, r-plotly, ggplotly

I created an interactive histogram in RStudio using ggplotly. When I export it as an .html file, the size is 30 MB or more. Now I want to embed it into my website but since the file size is so large, the website will take way too long to load.

I've tried `partial_bundle()` and also several html compressor/minifyier pages but nothing works. `partial_bundle()` doesn't reduce the file size and the compressor pages crash when I upload my file.

Any leads how I could reduce the file size?

Comment: Maybe you can use a bar chart instead of a histogram? When using `type = "histogram"` all the underlying data points are saved to the html file.

Comment: Plotly needs a big lib, so you probably won't be able to get much smaller than 5 MB unless you load the Plotly lib from somewhere else, but the extra 25MB you are seeing is probably data you've put there.

Comment: the simplest way to reduce the size is reduce the data.  as per other comment - there is a fixed overhead.  doing a bar chart of pre-calculated histogram results will be smaller that pushing all data in and generating histogram

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.